# How to pass more than one children - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I am developing a Table components where I need to populate the data in table body dynamically. I am maintaining the bodyData in arrayOf:[{}].  Cells will be created dynamically based on the values in the mock data. I need to pass four different data in body from mockdata. Now all are getting passed as children. Now I need to display one of the data in table cell in badge format. For this I am trying to pass multiple children so that I can render one of the children in badge format. But When I am passing more than one children component is rendering last children value only. Could any one help me how to pass (Brand value in the table in form of badge). Thanks in advance. I have wrote down the working code and mockdata.

```
import mockData from './mock-data/';

const createCell = cell => ({ key: cell.key, children: cell.children});
//tried to pass like cell => ({ key: cell.key, children: cell.customerName, 
//children:cell.customerAddr})

const createCellsForRow = cells => cells.map(cell => createCell(cell)); 

const StTable = () => {

  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState([]);

  const handleRowToggle = (event, metaData) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (selectedKey !== metaData.key) {
      setSelectedKey(metaData.key);
    }
  };

  const createRow = rowData => (
    {
      key: rowData.key,
      cells: createCellsForRow(rowData.cells),
      toggleAction: {
        metaData: { key: rowData.key },
        onToggle: handleRowToggle,
        isToggled: selectedKey === rowData.key,
        toggleLabel: rowData.toggleText,
      },
    }
  );

  const createRows = data => data.map(childItem => createRow(childItem));

  return (
    <Table
      summaryId="example-single-select"
      summary="This table shows an implementation of single row selection."
      numberOfColumns={4}
      cellPaddingStyle="standard"
      rowStyle="toggle"
      dividerStyle="horizontal"
      headerData={{
        selectAllColumn: {
          checkLabel: 'Single Selection',
        },
        cells: [
          { key: 'cell-0', id: 'toggle-0', children: 'Name' }, 
          { key: 'cell-1', id: 'toggle-1', children: 'Address' },
          { key: 'cell-2', id: 'toggle-2', children: 'Phone Number' },
          { key: 'cell-3', id: 'toggle-3', children: 'Brand' },//I need to pass this is as 
                                                               //badge format.
        ],
      }}
      bodyData={[
        {
          rows: createRows(mockData),
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default StTable;

//mockData Sample
[
    {
        "key":"row-0",
        toggleText:"txt",
        "cells":[
          { key: 'cell-0', id: 'toggle-0', children: 'ABC' },
          { key: 'cell-1', id: 'toggle-1', children: 'ABC123' },
          { key: 'cell-2', id: 'toggle-2', children: 'P1234567890' },
          { key: 'cell-3', id: 'toggle-3', children: ['A', 'B'] },
        ]
]

//I am trying to change the structure because (I need to display the brand in badge format)
[
    {
        "key":"row-0",
        toggleText:"txt",
        "cells":[
          { key: 'cell-0', id: 'toggle-0', customerName: 'ABC' },
          { key: 'cell-1', id: 'toggle-1', customerAddr: 'ABC123' },
          { key: 'cell-2', id: 'toggle-2', customerPhNo: 'P1234567890' },
          { key: 'cell-3', id: 'toggle-3', customerBrand: ['A', 'B'] },
        ]
]


//Table Component
const createCell = cell => ({ key: cell.key, children: cell.title });

const createCellsForRow = cells => cells.map(cell => createCell(cell));

const Table = () => {
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState([]);

  const handleRowToggle = (event, metaData) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (selectedKey !== metaData.key) {
      setSelectedKey(metaData.key);
    }
  };

  const createRow = rowData => (
    {
      key: rowData.key,
      cells: createCellsForRow(rowData.cells),
      toggleAction: {
        metaData: { key: rowData.key },
        onToggle: handleRowToggle,
        isToggled: selectedKey === rowData.key,
        toggleLabel: rowData.toggleText,
      },
    }
  );

  const createRows = data => data.map(childItem => createRow(childItem));

  return (
    <Table
      numberOfColumns={4}
      cellPaddingStyle="standard"
      rowStyle="toggle"
      dividerStyle="horizontal"
      headerData={{
        selectAllColumn: {
          checkLabel: 'Single Selection',
        },
        cells: [
          { key: 'cell-0', id: 'toggle-0', children: 'Name' },
          { key: 'cell-1', id: 'toggle-1', children: 'Address' },
          { key: 'cell-2', id: 'toggle-2', children: 'Phone Number' },
          { key: 'cell-3', id: 'toggle-3', children: 'Email Id' },
        ],
      }}
      bodyData={[
        {
          rows: createRows(mockData),
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: Can you share `Table` component also ??

Comment: @SujithSandeep, inside return I've gave the Table component.

Comment: No. The table syntax should be like `<table><tr><th></th></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table>`. If you are using like above, either you should have created a reusable component or you should have used any UI frameworks like Antd, MUI etc.., . What is your approach ?

Comment: Yes I am using Terra UI. From there I am using the Table component.

Comment: @SujithSandeep, I have added the Table component.

Comment: Okay.. Got it.. Let me check..